# Facebook Graph API GET http request, php

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a graph API GET request. It works in the Graph API explorer, but I can't seem to manage to have the application call it on its own.

I'm trying to retrieve the mutual friends in the user object. See documentation: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

```
    <?php

        $mutual = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_id."?".$access_token."/mutualfriends/".$other_fb_id));

    ?>
```

But this does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mixing URL arguments with `path`, it should be something like this (`?access_token=...` part should be placed at end):

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_id}/mutualfriends/{$other_fb_id}";
$url_with_token = $url . "?access_token={$access_token}";
$mutual = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_with_token));
```

Comment: thank you, that helps. however, that gives me an array with all the user's friends (the 2nd user), instead of all mutual friends. do you know why this may be happening? see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253861/facebook-graph-api-mutual-friends)