# Facebook Graph API mutual friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook graph API, I am trying to retrieve number of mutual friends 2 users have. However, I am getting number of friends of one of them instead.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    $mutual_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_id."/mutualfriends/".$other_fb_id."?".$access_token), true);

    $mutual_friends = $mutual_array['data'];
    $mutual_number = count($mutual_friends);

    ?>
```

$mutual_number gives the number of facebook friends $other_fb_id user has. And when I try to print_r $mutual_friends it gives all the friends the user has.

Anyone know what's going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a facebook api bug. Even though the information is symetrical, to get the number of mutual friends, you have to use the access token of the current user (user a), not of the other user you are checking with.

Answer (score 1):

In your code above $fb_id must have to be currently login user ID or it must be your application user. Facebook api do not allow to get mutual friends of any x-y-z user until they have joined your application.

Test it in [fb explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/mutualfriends/548573432)

Alternatively if you have friends of both users you can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function of PHP to get common ids from both friends array.

```
$result = array_intersect($user1_friends_array, $user2_friends_array);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: current $fb_id is indeed the currently logged in user in my code

Comment: it's the same thing in explorer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. The only thing you do is to change the order of placing your facebook id and friend's facebook id:

```
$mutual_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$other_fb_id."/mutualfriends/".$fb_id."?".$access_token), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like both your user id's are the same. Are you 100% sure they're not??

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with your code that I can see. As others have suggested try the graph explorer and check you can get the correct response there. Use '/me/mutualfriends/'.<some friend id>. If you can't get that to work, file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs and ping me here. I'm traveling right now and can't easily check this

Comment: hmm. just reported it to fb as well. 
or maybe I'm using the wrong access token? I'm using the one I get from fb when the user logs in to the app

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't broken (Im an engineer on Facebook platform fwiw). Just tried it, but it's tricky on my iPhone ;) access token is fine so long as $fb_id is the user the access token belongs to. Use '/me' instead, it makes more sense in this istance

Comment: oh cool. thanks, i changed to "me". i also changed to the other access token, of user #1 (I was using accesss token of user #2, now I understand that won't work, though I'm not sure why, it should go both ways). Anyhow this way it's working now. thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working, you should accept the other guys answer, he got the problem straight away ;) whilst the mutual friends between A&B and B&A is the same set, the access token always references the first edge. We should really throw an oauth exception when you get that wrong. Would you mind updating your bug with details of how you fixed it and for us to throw the error. Give me the bug id and I'll look into it at

Comment: sure, here it is https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/381053301911334?browse=search_4f387a247f8f42e12211650 the answer though was that the access token should be of the first use, I'll mention it

Answer (score 0):

With graph api it's done by requesting :

me/mutualfriends?user=SOME_USER_ID

if you and the SOME_USER_ID have mutualfriends you get the list of friends.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `access_token=` param:

```
$mutual_array = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$other_fb_id."/mutualfriends/".$fb_id."?access_token=".$access_token), true);
```